# Probability problem for independent events

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I have tried to solve a  probability  problem which is:

> In a certain game, you perform three tasks.  You flip a quarter, and
>   success would be heads.  You roll a single die, and success would be a
>   six.  You pick a card from a full playing-card deck, and success would
>   be picking a spades card.   If any of these task are successful, then
>   you win the game.  What is the probability of winning?

The way I have solved is:

Probability of getting head +  Probability of getting six on the dice +Probability of getting spades card
= $1/2 +1/6 + 13/52 = 11/12$

Have I done it correctly?

If that correct then I see the violation of the probability theory in my method of the calculation, because if I had opportunity to throw more dice or coins, the probability could exceed 1.

Comment: They key to evaluate the correct probability is that any of the tasks is successful... ie. you may get heads and not get six and spades. But you may get both heads and spades but not get six.

Comment: That does not work because of overlap. For a discussion on the formula provided by AnalysisStudento414, you may want to read about the inclusion-exclusion formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve problems like this is to compute the probabily of not winning instead. In order to not win you have to fail all the tasks. And since they are independant you can just multiply the probabilities. So
$$P(\text{lose}) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{4} = \frac{5}{16}$$

And therefore $P(\text{win}) = 1-P(\text{lose}) = \frac{11}{16}$.

Comment: Simple, indeed!

Comment: But what if i count the success first like:  $ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{4} \times  = 1/48 $ ?

Why can;t I do in this way?

Comment: @RayanAhmed take a look at my answer. It's not mandatory to have three successes in order to win the game.

Comment: @RayanAhmed what you are calucating is the chance that you win all of the tasks. In general the rules are that when $A$ and $B$ are independant then $P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$. And when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (i.e. can't happen at the same time) then $P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)$. What went wrong in your initial attempt is that you tried to use the second rule when the events where not disjoint, they could happen at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Call $A,B,C$ the successes at the different tasks. Using the inclusion-exclusion principle
$$P(\operatorname{win})=P(A)+P(B)+P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
So
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{13}{52} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{13}{52} - \frac{1}{6}\frac{13}{52}  + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{6}\frac{13}{52} = \frac{11}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that **any** of the tasks has to be successful, ie. you may get heads and fail at getting six and spades, but you also may get both heads and roll a six. At both chances you have won the game.

Let $A_1$ denote the event you get heads, $A_2$ the event you get six and $A_3$ the event you get spades.

$Pr(win) = P(A_1 A_2' A_3') + P(A_1' A_2 A_3') +P(A_1' A_2' A_3) + P(A_1 A_2 A_3) + P(A_1' A_2 A_3) + P(A_1 A_2' A_3) + P(A_1 A_2 A_3')$

So

$$Pr(win) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{4} +... + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{33}{48} = \frac{11}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way is to take the complement of  $P$(none of the events occur)

$ 1 - \dfrac12\cdot\dfrac56\cdot\dfrac34 = \dfrac{11}{16}$